# Substituting/overriding Windows CRT for low-level debugging

Tags: c++, crt

I have been looking at [some Source Engine code](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/master/mp/src/public/tier0/memoverride.cpp) recently, and in the very low layers the developers have a file called `memoverride.cpp` which overrides some core runtime facilities for debugging purposes. This involves re-implementing the entire interface that the CRT provides (eg. functions for `malloc` and `msize`, stubs for `_crtBreakAlloc`, etc.) and routing the calls through a custom class to keep track of allocations and the like.

I thought this was interesting and tried to recreate it myself out of curiosity, but when linking I get conflicts between the custom implementation and `libucrt`'s symbols. If I use the `/Zl` compiler option on Windows to not link against the Windows CRT, I then get all sorts of undefined symbols regarding the rest of the CRT functionality (the string functions, for example).

Is this approach advisable for low-level debugging, and if so, what's the correct way to accomplish it? Would it require not linking against the CRT at all, or only choosing parts of it?